# What is the fastest way to upload files to Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: migration, file-upload

I have more of an admin question - we are migrating from local document fileshare to SharePoint 2013 and I am seeking ways to quickly upload 700 Gigs of data to several document libraries (Functions).There are several filtering mechanisms implemented in our organization as well as some exceptions from our countries ISPs - so the upload takes a lot of time, literally days. So, my questions are:

1) What is the fastest way to upload files (keeping the folder structure) to the SharePoint?
2) Is there a difference using the Sync function or simply moving files through Explorer view?
3) Any other ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

700 Gigs is not too much. you can do it manual(drag and drop from explorer or manually upload to library).

one thing is maximum size of a single file, then set the upload limit accordingly so that you dont fall in issue "upload limit exceeded".

Increase the Session time out settings for IIS and also for browser if you decide to manual upload.

Try to upload the data off peak hours so that you can get the maximum resources.

Other method is use 3rd party tools or write code using web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom code to upload your files to sharepoint, but it would require a development effort. You can also check:

http://www.infoworld.com/d/microsoft-windows/how-migrate-file-shares-sharepoint-2010-179031

One Free tool : http://spbulkdocumentimport.codeplex.com/

There are lot of 3rd party tool available. You can evaluate these as per your requirement.

http://www.avepoint.com/file-system-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/

http://www.metavistech.com/category/migration-suite

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/how-to-bulk-copy-files-to-sharepoint-101